# Test whether a point is inside a path or not

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's a question that I couldn't find any answer to by googling: I've got a path in tikz, drawn by `\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {...};`. Is there a way to test whether a given point `(x,y)` is inside the path or outside?

More concretely, I'd like to do something like

```
if (x,y) inside path:
   \draw (x,y) rectangle (x+1,y+1);
end
```

I understand that tikz can in principle determine the interior of a path for its `\fill` command, but I couldn't find any way to actually return true/false for an arbitrary point.

EDIT:

A minimal example of what I actually want to do is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=2pt] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {
        (-6.2,0) (-5,-5)  (5,-5) (6,0) (5,3)
        (3,3)  (1,6) (-4,6)
    };
    
    \draw[gray] (-8,-8) grid (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I want to do is paint every box of the grid black if its center is inside the curve (to get sort of a pixelized version of the potato shape). Do I really have to implement the ray casting method by hand?

[image: Potato shape]

Comment: This feels like a xy-problem. Can you make a [mre] and give a bit of background information what you want to do with this information?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to include a minimal example. Maybe I'll actually have to implement the ray-casting method by hand...